# Change the default group of a first time logged in oauth user in Openshift

Tags: openshift

Currently, if a user logs in via oauth to the Openshift cluster, they are automatically added to the `system:authenticated:oauth` group, I could now add/remove  roles to this group to modify the default access rights.

Is there a way to change the default group the user gets assigned to?

I am using Openshift on version 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to change the default group the user gets assigned to?

Do you want to set the default authenticated group except system:authenticated:oauth ? If yes, then you can not change the group. Like system:authenticated:oauth, some groups are configured statically in the source code [0]. And the groups are binding to the users automatically. If you remove the group from user, then it will revert quickly by reconciliation tasks which force the desired group to assign.

[0] https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/release-4.1/pkg/cmd/server/bootstrappolicy/constants.go#L36

```
// groups
const (
    AuthenticatedGroup      = "system:authenticated"
    AuthenticatedOAuthGroup = "system:authenticated:oauth"
    UnauthenticatedGroup    = "system:unauthenticated"
    ClusterAdminGroup       = "system:cluster-admins"
...
```